# Is there any way to horizontal progress bar in android

Tags: android

I want to make a vertical progress bar can i rotate horizontal progress bar and make it vertical or is there any easy way to make a vertical progress bar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:rotation="degree"` param to your ProgressBar

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:rotation="90" />
```

[reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:rotation)